# Not allowed to secure GraphQL endpoint with JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, graphql, postgraphql

I'm running an express server and just put up JWT protection on my endpoints. I was testing out my `/graphql` endpoint and I am receiving a 403 `Not allowed to provide a JWT token` error. My other endpoints work fine, so I don't believe it is an issue with the JWT signing or verification. Any ideas?

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

var app = express();

var jwtCheck = jwt({
   secret: new Buffer(config.secret, 'base64'),
   audience: aud,
   issuer: iss
});

// enforce on all endpoints
app.use(jwtCheck);

app.use('/', postgraphql(config.db_string, config.db_schema, {
    development: true,
    log: true,
    secret: config.secret,
    graphiql: true,
}));
```

[image: Postman Request landing on a vanilla graphql endpoint]

Comment: It's impossible to tell without some code...

Comment: @miparnisari There's not much to share. It's a vanilla `graphql` endpoint on an `express` server

Comment: Can you share the code for this endpoint? Also, there must be a middleware function doing the JWT protection, can you share that?

Comment: @miparnisari Gotcha, updated :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But you shared the code of the middleware functions, and we need the code for the endpoint too.

Comment: The `postgraphql` endpoint creates the `graphql`. That is everything.

Comment: What does the call to `postgraphql(` return? I expect it to be a function, right? In that case, shouldn't the code be `app.get('/postgraphql', postgraphql ... )`?

Comment: @miparnisari It creates the `/graphql`. So if we had, `/postgraphql` instead of `/` it would create an endpoint at `/postgraphql/graphql`. From the endpoint, I can access `graphql` how you would normally access it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that the call to `postgraphql(` cannot create an endpoint. It probably just does something like `req.db = postgraphql`. So that later on you can use it on every route. Try adding and edpoint with `app.get('/postgraphql', ...)`

Comment: @miparnisari I'm pretty sure it does. Without the `express-jwt` on my endpoints, it works perfectly fine at `/graphql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, problem was with not passing the correct parameters to `PostgraphQL`. If you pass a JWT token in the Authorization header to `PostgraphQL`, it expects a secret. If the secret does not exist, then `PostgraphQL` will throw the error 403 `Not allowed to provide a JWT` error.

Comment: I believe this behaviour is fixed in v3.3.0